# how to use NSURLConnection (NSMutableRequest) timeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to timeout the connection or make the connection invalidate or display an alert saying "connection time out", if the response is not received (or connection delegate methods not called) after 5 secs or 10 secs (a certain time period). Does anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your `NSURLConnection's` delegate is set and responds to the `connection:didFailWithError:` method. A connection always calls either this method or `connectionDidFinishLoading:` upon connection completion.

your timeout is received in `connection:didFailWithError:` so here you can display that connection has timed out

Comment: thanks steve. I did the same thing which you mentioned. I have set the timeout interval of NSMutableURLRequest to 5 secs: [NSMutableURLRequestObj setTimeoutInterval:5.0]; but after 5 secs none of the connection delegate methods is getting called. I had debugged the code (using breakpoints) and I found that after 20 or 25 seconds, the connection delegate methods didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData and connectionDidFinishLoading are called. I want to invalidate this type of connections if response is not received withinn 5 or 10 secs. Can you please explain to me how should I achieve this?

Comment: can you post the URL where you are trying this?

Comment: Actually its juz a local URL. You will not be able to hit that from your end. The server is not on public domain. M sorry. Basically what I want to do is if I am not getting response in 10 secs, then I have to display an alert to the user saying "Connection Time out".

Comment: try the time out interval as 0.00000001.. if it calls the didFailwithError than there is nothing wrong with your code and something fishy on the server side. I tested like this . this works fine for me. Aur baki kuch keh nahi sakta main :P

Comment: Aapka bahut bahut dhanyawaad Steve Jobs "INDIAN" :) ;) :D

Comment: Hey steve, I have tried this: [loginRequest setTimeoutInterval:0.00000001]; (loginRequest is an object of NSMutableURLRequest) but the control is not coming to this method: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error ; but according to you it must call this method. so, can you please tell me what the problem might be. I m stuck into this since morning (IST). Plz help me.